# Spritekit contact detection crash(EXC_breakpoint)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, crash, game-physics, contacts

I set up a game where the player controlls a ship and shoots the incomming enemies. When One Bullet and ONE enemy make contact, there is no crash but when two bullets hit 2 different enemis i got a crash in the following func.(EXC_Breakpoint) (all bullets has the same physicCategory and all enemy has the same physicsCategory.

How can I solve this?
Thanks!

```
 if body1.categoryBitMask==PhysicsCategories.Bullet && body2.categoryBitMask==PhysicsCategories.Enemy && (body2.node?.position.x)!<self.size.width{
```

Answer (score 1):

All Sprite-Kit collisions are between 2 bodies - you can’t have 2 bullets hit 2 enemies. If it looks as though 1 bullet has hit 2 enemies at the same time, what you will actually get is a call to `didBegin()` for the bullet and one enemy and another call for the bullet and the other enemy. However, if you do `removeFromParent()` for the bullet for the first collision, then you may have problems for the second collision as the bullet node will be `nil`, although the bullet’s physics body will still be there.

Search on SO for “Sprite Kit multiple collisions” as this is a common problem and there are several ways to handle it. The easiest way to describe is instead of doing `removeFromParent` for nodes that should be “destroyed”, add them to an array (or more properly, a set). Then in `didFinishUpdate`, iterate over this set and remove all the nodes that are in it.